# Problems integrating Leadbolt with Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, ads

I am trying to integrate LeadBolt adds in my game. I have successfully integrated their sdk and receiving ads on an android project. But encountering problems with the android port of the libgdx. Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements LeadBoltInterface{

    private AdController ad;
    String Offer_Wall = "406654115", Alert_Simple = "205987650",
            INTERSTITIA = "198781435", ReEngagement = "399870327",
            App_Audio = "307311112", APP_AD_ID = "141754365";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;
        initialize(new RocketMouse(this), cfg);

        ad = new AdController(this, APP_AD_ID);
        ad.loadAd();
        ad.loadStartAd(App_Audio, ReEngagement);


    }

    @Override
    public void showMyFullScreenAd() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      ad.loadAd();
//      ad.loadStartAd(App_Audio, ReEngagement);
    }

}
```

My manifest file is also well configured. But the application crashes on start up due to the following lines in onCreate()

ad.loadAd();
ad.loadStartAd(App_Audio, ReEngagement);

java.lang.runtimeexception: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

.....
03-01 19:05:50.738: E/AndroidRuntime(32400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I am new to android but familiar with libgdx. Please help me.